# Autostart/run "./abcd" file/program on xubuntu

Tags: linux, autorun, xubuntu

How do I create an autostart entry for a program I have to start like this:

```
/home/user/Desktop/app/./applicationname
```

Help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/home/user/.bash_profile` and add a line that says `/home/user/Desktop/app/./applicationname &`, should do it.

Comment: I doubt that that works as intended. It will run the program in the background every time a terminal is started.

Comment: if I try that command just in my terminal, it will not run since the app complains of not having the neccesary config files. The app needs to start in the folder... 
@larsmans any ideas ??

Comment: @GijsHompes: How about changing the command to `cd dirItNeedsToBeIn`, and on the next line, what @Hbcdev suggested.

Comment: This isn't the way to do it. It launches the app every time I open a terminal. I only want one terminal launching when the desktop is ready.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said .bash_profile, wasn't thinking straight. Have updated the answer.

Comment: The application runs in terminal. But that's hidden...is there a way to see it?

Comment: Ah, in that case try `xterm -e /home/user/Desktop/app/./applicationname &`

Comment: This should be dead simple...I feel embarassed... :)
First : the .bash_profile was empty in the first place, I find that weird
Second: the file looks like `xterm -e /home/firefox/Desktop/Project-OSRM/./osrm-routed &`
Third:nothing nothing happens, and I can verify if the program is running by going to an url...

Comment: That's not necessarily weird. What do you mean about the file? If it now works, don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Start by getting something that works in a terminal. So play around with `xterm -e /home/firefox/Desktop/Project-OSRM/./osrm-routed &` until it opens a new terminal and runs your programme there. When that works, copy it into your bash profile.

Comment: Then run `cd /correct/directory` first! And put that in your bash profile too.

Comment: I have confirmed the individual steps. and have placed them in my .bash_profile. Yet..no action, nor after a restart of X nor after rebooting the entire system.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13759/discussion-between-gijs-hompes-and-hbcdev)